# Semantic shift in "around"

Tags: meaning, semantics, historical-change, literary-english

I'm interested in the use of "around" as a synomym for "about, concerning, related to", which doesn't seem to be recorded in current dictionaries. I'd call it an academic/pseudo-academic usage and tho' I dislike it, I find it interesting and wonder when it first appeared and whether it's increasing in academia and in media like *The Guardian*. Some examples:

> Many of the procedural issues **around** policy implementation were being addressed. [...] Whilst there are perfectly understandable reasons for this, due to the late entry of women into the academy, and particularly into the kinds of discipline represented at this university, it was felt important to 'problematize' gender in the management context, both in terms of issues **around** 'representation' and in terms of the practices of the incumbents: the growing literature on male managers suggests that they may experience constraints in their own work which may be related to particular constructions of masculinity, and Heads of Department were therefore seen as key informants in this sense (see Kerfoot and Knights 1993). [...] Parker and Jarry's (1995) Foucauldian analysis sees the new academic subjectivity as inexorably complicit in the production and reproduction of a Fordist mass higher education. At the same time, they contribute to a debate which is still going on, **around** the idea of 'active citizenship' in higher education. ("Gendering the Management of Power in Higher Education", Jackie Goode and Barbara Bagilhole, in *Gender, Work and Organization*, Vol. 5, Num. 3, July 1998.)
>
> Feminist critiques of menopause have been beneficial in opening up important public health debates **around** menopause. [...] Extending earlier feminist critiques **around** menopause and HRT, this paper discusses a critical feminist engagement **around** issues of women's perceived non-compliance with HRT. ("Managing menopause: a critical feminist engagement", in *Scand J Public Health*, Dec. 27, 1999)

Comment: As far as I am concerned, the objectionable aspect of the text you cite is not the use of *around* to mean *about, concerning, related to* -- or even its excessive repetition, which is certainly mildly irritating -- but the piece's opaqueness, lack of expressive focus and turgid overall style. Unfortunately, such writing is very common in academic prose.

Comment: @Erik: So I guess you'd have liked it even less if the writer(s) had included what I see as a "deleted" word before each use of **around** (*centred, centring,* or similar).

Comment: There's definitely been a semantic shift. Searching Google books for "questions around" in the 19th century, I couldn't find a single instance of this usage. Searching Google books in the 21st century, most of the hits for "questions around" fell into this usage. When did this happen? 1966: *"Some of the questions around handling sex behavior are nothing new"*. 1950: *"Questions around the distribution of funds, the supervision and the administration of programs have been controversial."*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - No, I have no objection to either 'around' when used in this sense, or 'centred around'. You might be right that this usage of 'around' arises from the elision of 'centred'. Another possibility is that 'around' is being substituted for 'surrounding'.

Comment: In most (but not all) of these cases, "surrounding" would be a good  substitute; the "issues" seem to be incidental (linguistic, procedural) rather than fundamental to the core subjects being referred to. In at least one case ("[...]around the idea of 'active citizenship'[...]") I'd be inclined to think that an overused wording pattern has simply led to an error.

Comment: I don't think this is a surprising linguistic development. It's simply the extension of the meaning *"in the neighborhood of"* for *"around"* from the literal (which it has had since the 17th century, if not earlier) to the metaphorical.

Comment: @Erik I'd agree that it's not the MOST objectionable aspect of the texts, but I think it fits that context v. well. That's why I wanted texts that were, as you say, opaque, unfocused and turgid. But altho' bad academic writing has received a lot of attention, I haven't seen this particular usage discussed or analysed, which is why I wanted to raise it here.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks. I've only started to notice it in the past decade, but I assumed it began much earlier. It's not a surprising development, but what about its psychology? I think it's motivated by pretension and neophilia. Another buzz from the hive-mind.

Comment: Are you sure it's not recorded in current dictionaries? [ODO's definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/around#around__13) seems to cover it.

Comment: I suspect it's a combination of the metaphoric use that @PeterShor refers to, and a phonetic shift in _issues surrounding_. Many words have come from shifting phonemes in phrases like this, and the confluence with the metaphor probably accelerated it.

Comment: Is "around" not being used as "about"?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is incorrect to assume 'around' is synonymous with 'about' in the contexts you supplied.  'About' means something direct like 'concerning' and often points to single causes, persons, or things, focussing on these; while 'around' has a much more passive meaning, sort of like 'surrounding', and is often used to highlight a plurality of influences surrounding the central object of discussion.

Answer (score 1):

"Around" certainly can replace "related toward".  It is usually modified my an adjective placed before hand like "revolving" or "based".   I think the missing modifying adjective in many cases forces a loss of context amongst non-native English listeners unused to slang of this kind.  I think it is on par with the same men and women who start sentences with the word "basically" and then proceed to fumble with the explanation. Oh and that dude we all know that finishes sentences with "per se" without having isolated anything "in itself".

Answer (score 1):

The word "around", depending on the surrounding context may be used as an alternative to words that normally tend to draw attention to a particular issue being addressed. Words like: revolving, related toward, regarding etc.